# Jboss-deployment-structure.xml don't read on EAR File

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, ear, jboss-eap-6

I created a file called jboss-deployment-structure.xml and I put the file in the META-INF directory of the EAR project.
My ear has then the following structure:

```
MyEar.ear
-> META-INF
------> Application.xml
------> Jboss-deployment-structure.xml
-> MyWar.war
```

How do I make deploy within JBoss EAP 6.2 I read this issue:

javax.persistence.Table.indexes () [Ljavax / persistence / Index;

This problem is related to the JPA 2.0 version of JBOSS while I use Hibernate JPA 2.1.

If I enter the file jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WEB-INF directory of the WAR project and install only the WAR file, the web-based software works without problems.

What is wrong?
Thank you,
Vincenzo

This is content of Jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jpa" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javaee.api" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to exclude your [sub-deployments](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile).

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jpa" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javaee.api" />
    </exclusions>    
</deployment>
<sub-deployment name="your.war">
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jpa" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javaee.api" />
    </exclusions>
</sub-deployment>
```

This would need to be done for each sub-deployment you want those exclusions on.

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic ... it works without problems, but I had to correct your example ...

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jpa" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javaee.api" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
<sub-deployment name="MyWar.war">
    <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jpa" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
        </exclusions>
</sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Oops, fixed. Thanks for catching that.